# how to set the locaction in nginx.conf for removing URL's trailing slash?

Tags: nginx, vue.js, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

Today I used two servers for nginx, the content of nginx.conf as follows:

```
#192.168.2.98
server {
    listen 8091;
    location ^~ /ttank {
        alias /develop/servers-running/front/vue-public/dist;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /ttank/index.html;
     }
 }



#192.168.2.97
location /ttank {
   proxy_pass http://192.168.2.98:8091;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_redirect off;
}
```

I can access the *192.168.2.98:8091/ttank* by enter address: *http://192.168.2.98:8091/ttank* in chrome, I also can access *192.168.2.98*'s ttank by entering the address *http://192.168.2.97/ttank/*,  but when I change the addres *http://192.168.2.97/ttank/* into *http://192.168.2.97/ttank*, my chrome entered into waiting status forever, the only difference between two addresses is the last "/", I don't know how to modify the config file for removing the last "/" when accessing *ttank* by *192.168.2.97*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try usinge a rewrite rule to get rid of the ending slashes

```
location /ttank {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 break;
    ...;
    ...;
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

it should do it